# Add XML Serialized object to APK so it is copied into the app's private files directory

Tags: android, xml, apk, xml-serialization, android-resources

I have a desktop application that produces resource / data files for my android app. These are XML text files that store instances of my custom data class. These objects are serialized using the Simple XML Serialization library. In my android app, I'd like to instantiate objects from this XML serialization class.

I like to add these xml files to Android Studio so they are included in the APK on device install and are placed, for example, in the private app directory "files", to which getFilesDir() is mapped. I can't find a way to do that.

If I add these xml files to the Android XML resource folder, I need to use Android's XML resource parser, and can not use the Simple XML library.

Any tips? I feel I made a wrong design choice seeing how restrictive the resource bundling is.

Thanks, Kind regards,
Harmen

Comment: "I can't find a way to do that" -- there is no automatic support for this. You can always copy the data from a resource or asset to a file yourself, if the file does not already exist. "If I add these xml files to the Android XML resource folder, I need to use Android's XML resource parser" -- if you use raw resources or assets, you can get an `InputStream` on your content, which appears to be supported by Simple XML.

Comment: Thanks. That indeed solves my problem! Posted it as an answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

As per CommonsWare's comment: the solution was adding it to the raw resource folder, then you can access it using:

```
InputStream xmlExerciseInputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.myresource);
MyClass myClass = serializer.read(MyClass.class, xmlExerciseInputStream);
```